# what will be the regular expression of date format 'dd-M-y'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

what will be the regular expression of date format like `'01-Aug-12'.`

I have the date format of `dd-M-y` in asp.net application and want to validate it from `asp.net regular expression validator control`.

Comment: Have you read "regular expressions 101"?

Comment: Your date format does not match your example. Do you mean `dd-MMM-yy` as date format?

Comment: @Talha: it is **any** article about regex basics

Comment: are ok with using asp.net validation controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be too elegant, but if you want to use regex to validate dates, it is here:

### The regex with explanation

```
(
  (
    31-(Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)|                                   # months with 31 days
    (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|   # months with 30 or 31 days
    (0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-Feb                                             # February up to 28th
  )
  -\d\d                                                                 # any two digits represent the year
)|
(
    29-Feb-([02468][048]|[13579][26])                                   # February 29th
)
```

This regex doesn't accept invalid dates like `00-Aug-00`, `32-Aug-00` and `29-Feb-01` while accepting valid dates including leap days (`29-Feb-04`). **Note** that we assume `00` stands for year `2000`, not `1900`. So, we accepted `29-Feb-00` as leap day!

### In one line:

See it [in action](http://regexr.com?31ucv):

```
((31-(Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)|(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)|(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-Feb)-\d\d)|(29-Feb-([02468][048]|[13579][26]))
```

### Case-insensitivity

In [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), add an `i` as second parameter:

```
var re = new RegExp(regexStr, "i");
```

In ASP.NET, use [RegexOptions.IgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

```
Regex re = new Regex(regexStr,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: i have updated your regex expression to support the month(s) in capital as well as small letters. thanks :) ((31-(Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec|jan|mar|may|jul|aug|oct|dec)|(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|jan|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)|(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-[fF]eb)-\d\d)|(29-[fF]eb-([02468][048]|[13579][26]))

Comment: @Talha You can use case-insensitive option of your regex flavor, it may be shorter and easier.

Comment: @Talha Updated answer to explain.

Comment: Nice regex solution.  Perhaps you should also explain why he shouldn't use regex to validate a date.

Answer (score 5):

A very basic format check would be:

```
\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{2}
```

See for yourself [here](http://regexr.com?31ubr).

To actually validate, we need a day check like @Brijesh Gandhi suggested and then add a complete month list like this:

```
([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}
```

If you want to allow for lowercase months like `aug`, you can add the case-insensivity modifier `?i:` like this...

```
([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(?i:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}
```

...but that will also allow a month like e.g. `aUg` - it might be most correct to only allow the first character to be upper- or lowercase.

```
([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-([Jj]an|[Ff]eb|[Mn]ar|[Aa]pr|[Mm]ay|[Jj]un|[Jj]ul|[Aa]ug|[Ss]ep|[Oo]ct|[Nn]ov|[Dd]ec)-\d{2}
```

See this final version in action [here](http://regexr.com?31ucj).

**Please note that this still will not detect invalid dates like 30-Feb-12.** A regexp not accepting those special dates will be very long/ugly. Even using  Javascript's `Date.parse(...)`/`new Date(...)` will not help detect those as it happily accepts the above mentioned, non-existant date, and return the 1st of March. So to be 100% correct, you need to either do complex coding yourself, or use a library like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

**Edit 1:** Shortened @Brijesh Gandhi's day check a bit, updated Regexr link.

**Edit 2:** Remark on correctness.

Comment: No - I though we were going for a simple check, but of course you're right. Improved my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Why regexp?
I would validate it using

```
DateTime.TryParse(...)
```

Anyway a basic form of regex could be

```
[0-3][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]
```

which could be better than nothing.

Comment: i know that, but i want to validate it on client side

Answer (score 3):

Regular Expression is definitely not the way to go here. We could do a simple [`Date.Parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) which returns `NaN` if the date is not valid.

```
var myDate = '01-Aug-12​';
var isValidDate = !isNaN( Date.parse( myDate ));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this regex

```
([1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[3][0-1])-[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z][a-zA-Z]-[0-9][0-9]
```

`00-aug-12` is not valid date according this regex `[0-3][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex for every combination of the date format `dd-MMM-yy`:

```
[0123][0-9]-[JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptvc]-[0-9][0-9]
```

Note how the month part is overly strict, while you may still be able to supply an invalid date. Maybe it is better to try to parse the date and check whether it is valid.